# How can I check from a URL that an .html extension is present or not?

Tags: java, string, url

I store a list of URLs in a string array, and I want to check whether there is an `.html` extension present or not at the end of each URL.

```
String line[]={"https://google.com","http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login.html"};

for( int i=0;i<=line.length;i++) { 
    int m=line[i].length();
    System.out.println(" lenth of url "+m);
}
```

I am unable to find that logic.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either the URL contains `.html` or it doesn't. What it maps to at the server is up to the server, and not determinable by the client. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a `String` ends with a suffix, you can use `String#endsWith()`:

```
String line[]={"https://google.com","http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login.html"};

for (String ln : line) {
    if (ln.endsWith(".html")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```